# Can I use one internal hard drive in different PCs?

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, windows-10

I have an HDD internal hard drive in my desktop with windows 10 OS system now. However, I am thinking to sell my desktop, but I want to keep that HDD drive because the HDD contain a lot of personal files and the Windows 10 OS system authorization. So, I am wondering that if I am going to buy a new desktop later (without the hard drive), can I still use the old HDD drive without reinstall the OS system? In other words, can I just plug out my HDD drive from the old PC and plug into my new PC directly? I know I have to reinstall all drivers for all the new hardware, but is any way to avoid that? Because if I reinstall the OS system my files and Windows 10 authorization will gone. (I bought the Windows 8 authorization when I was a student with a student disscount and recentlly upgrande to Windows 10.)

Comment: Please take a look, HTH: http://www.howtogeek.com/226510/how-to-use-your-free-windows-10-license-after-changing-your-pc%E2%80%99s-hardware/

Comment: You may be able to sysprep the machine in order to get it to transfer to new hardware. I did this when transferring a Windows 7 HDD to a new PC.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf - While SysPrep will work, the author would need another Windows 10 license, the existing Windows 10 license cannot be transfered.

Comment: @Ramhound oh really? The free upgrade license isn't transferable? That's a strange move on Microsoft's part but oh well.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf - The literal Windows 10 installation ( when upgraded from a previous installation) is activated by a digital entitlement license which is locked to the machine that was upgraded.  If you upgraded from an Retail license, you could format the first machine, and install the Retail license and upgrade that but the digital entitlement you recieve is locked to the machine that recieves it.  **After July 29th you will have to supply a Windows 10 license, in order to upgrade to Windows 10, which means you could at that point use SysPrep.**

Comment: @Ramhound wow alright thank you! I had no idea that's how they were doing things.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf - Microsoft is simply delaying the money they earn from users purchasing Windows Upgrade licenses for one year, Windows 10 is not free, a single user cannot get Windows 10 on every single machine if they only have a single WIndows license they paid for.  The "upgrade" to Windows 10 that is being offered, is more of an "update" offer, since the end result will be more users on Windows 10 which can be sustained.  Microsoft will be basically writting the money they lose, from those "free" upgrades, off at some point.

Comment: I had an online chat with Microsoft representative, he said the license is transferable or not depends on what type of license we buy. Since I bought my license separately, my license is transferable and I am also able to transfer my Windows 8 and 10 OS after July. However, he also said the license is a limited transfer for abuse reason, (but he did not tell me how to define an abuse reason). So, there is only one question left for me, can I just simply plug out my hard drive from the old PC, and directly plug into new PC?

Comment: @Mr.111 - Your Windows 10 license is not transferable.  You can transfer the Windows 8 license, upgrade that to Windows 10, and get rid of the installation on the old PC.

Comment: But the Microsoft representative said these sentences to me: "If you want you can create a Windows 10 Media Tool. You can use DVD/USB with at least 4GB storage size." and "The version that you can install using that key is Windows 8.1 and windows 10 Pro edition." In addition, I asked exactly "So, that means I can use the key to active any Windows 8.1 and 10, even after July 28, right?" and the answer is "Yes! Absolutely!". Why would he say that to me? Did I or he misunderstand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you got the free Windows 10 upgrade, the license for that is not transferable to another machine.

Theoretically, you could do as you suggest and just plug the drive into a new computer, boot from it, and wait for drivers to update automatically. The Windows 10 instance would then report as non-genuine (and enforce restrictions) until you purchased a new license.

If your main goal is to be able to use your accumulated files, it may be best to get a USB-to-SATA adapter and just treat the drive as external storage.

Comment: Provided the Windows 8 license is not an OEM license, the author can format the existing machine, and install Windows 8 on the new machine.  Once that is done the Windows 8 machine itself can be upgraded to Windows 10, that would be the only way to get Windows 10 on the new machine for free.

Comment: @Ramhound That is an alternative. However, OP mentioned that they'd prefer to avoid having to reinstall stuff. Also, this is viable only until the end of the Win 10 free upgrade period, scheduled to end July 29th.

Comment: I am sorry I did not mention that my license is not OEM, I bought it from Microsoft online store. However, the Microsoft representative told me I can transfer my license for both Windows 8.1 and 10 (of course, I have to choose one of them) even after July as long as I am not "abuse" my license, but he did not tell me how to define the "abuse". Since the representative said there is a limited time to do the transfer, my question becomes how to avoid the installation to transfer my hard drive from my old PC to new PC?

Comment: @Mr.111 - I already knew it wasn't OEM does not change the fact the Windows 10 license is.  As I said you can install Windows 8 on the new machine and accept the upgrade, the Windows 10 license on the old machine, would have to be removed.